# Web app for drag and drop, save as PDF and print

Tags: html, web

I've been tasked to make a web app that users can drag and drop images to a container, depending on the size of the image, it needs to be able to snap in to place until the container is full.

I'm only a beginner programmer, I'm not too sure how to even begin (I've been "googling" for the last couple of days). I'm only going to host the app on a local server.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

- Would Python be the best bet here?
- Is a Web App even a good approach to this? I'm only going with a web app, so users can access through localhost.
- There's no data stored (yet). Just saving as pdf and printing.
- I'm not sure what other features will be added in the future, but would be good to have future proofing.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. SO is more focused in "closed" code questions the type we can see code, spot mistakes, and point some resolution and help everyone with the same problem. Members can get upset when someone use SO as a programming school, that's why you been downvoted three times now...

Comment: Wayyyy to broad. Where are the images? File system? Already displayed to the user in a UI? Is the container visual? What defines the container as being full, image count or dimensions? If this is just done via local host a web based solution is probably no ideal. Where is the pdf saved too? What *exactly* does it consist of? Please read the [help] and take the [tour] for more info on what sort of questions to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispite of my comment I'll give you some directions...

I'll upset a bunch of people, but I don't think python and web are a good match...

You should study a client-side framework like react, that has NPM modules to easily drag and drop, and to organize children in containers in smart ways.

The PDF part is tricky, theres a thing call ghostscript that can "printscreen" a html rendered page and make pdfs, or some tool that do the same using a headless browser.

Can be done, but won't be trivial...